# How to convert decimal values in tofixed format in postgresql

Tags: database, decimal, postgresql-9.3

My table column in decimal format like this
My column value is:

```
   4523
   1236.23
   1240.5
   2535.2
```

I would like to this format:

```
   4523.00
   1236.33
   1240.50
   2535.20
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `to_char()` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`to_char`.

```
SELECT to_char(1231.123, '9999999999.00');
```

See: [data type formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

The manual is your friend.